# how to fetch array of input values from html to JS

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, salesforce-lightning

I have posted the same question on salesforce.stackexchange.com below is the link

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/283596/how-to-fetch-input-field-value-in-js-in-lwc?noredirect=1#comment426016_283596

But in the comments people suggested this is not much related to salesforce it is more of a Javascript thing so I am posting the same here, please take a look and suggest from html and js point of view.

*HTML syntax seem different as it is lightning web component of salesoforce not angular, and also please help me to understand the same behavior in angular and I will do it in salesforce accordingly*

in the below html code I am iterating 2 lists linItemData(11 records) and studyData(20 records)

```
<table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
              <template if:true={studyData}>
                <template for:each={studyData} for:item="sData">
                  <th key={sData}>
                    <div class="tablename slds-p-bottom_medium"></div>{sData.Visit_Name__c}
                  </th>
                </template>
              </template>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <template if:true={lineItemData}>
              <template for:each={lineItemData} for:item="sLineItem">
                <tr key={sLineItem}>
                  <template for:each={studyData} for:item="sData">
                    <td key={sData.Id}>
                      <lightning-input variant="label-hidden" class="fieldSize" type="number" step="0.01"
                        label="visitValue" data-key={sData.Id} onchange={visitValueChange} placeholder="00.00">
                      </lightning-input>
                    </td>
                  </template>
                </tr>
              </template>
            </template>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

and I am getting an expected result with all the required input fields on the UI like below:

[image]

now I need to fetch the input value for all v20s for example for v1 (first column name)should have array of 11 input records.

JS is as below:

```
visitValueChange(event) {
    this.studyData
        .find(item => item.Id === event.currentTarget.dataset.key)
        .visitValue = event.target.value;
}
```

I have tried everything I could but the visitValue can hold only the 1 recent value for example if I add 1 on first input field, two on 2nd, three on 3rd and so on after that I hit a button which is calling a JS function to see the studyData array but it has only the recent value which is 3 not all 1,2 and 3 values entered and the requirement is to have an array of all the input values added on all the 11  input fileds for all the columns. 
Please help me to suggest any workaround for the same.

Comment: This question is tagged as Angular, but the syntax of `<template if:true={lineItemData}>` doesn't look like Angular to be, neither the `if:true` nor the single curly braces. Doesn't look quite like what I've seen of React either. What is this really>

Comment: @kshetline, my apologies. I have updated my question please suggest any work around

Comment: If possible, please let me know how to do it in angular and I will do it accordingly in salesforce.

Comment: For that, you have to keep a track of the input fields corresponding to a column and iterate the fields to get the input.

Comment: Could you please be kind to provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues:

- The way your data is designed
- Linking the input with the correct record

### Data model

Depending on your context, you could say that:

- Each line is a record with columns being attributes of record (col1, col2, ...)
- Each column is a record with lines being attributes of record (row1, row2, ...)
- Each cell is a record identified with an id like `x_y` (1_1, 1_2, ...)

I would probably recommend option 1 as it's the most common representation.

This means you have to prepare / create records like this:

```
const myRecords = [
    { 
        id: 1,
        col1: 0,
        col2: 0,
        ...
    }, {
        id: 2,
        col1: 0,
        col2: 0,
        ...
    }
]
```

### Linking input to correct record

Use [LWC datatabel](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation) to create your table. You can then get what you need using custom data types. This would allow to use properly designed records (one by line and each columns is an attribute) without any transformation.

### Display using the provided HTML

Unfortunatly there are some limits in Salesforce (with the HTML you provided) so you need to transform your records into this.

```
const myRecords = [
    { 
        id: 1,
        columns: [
            { id: 1, value: 0 },
            { id: 2, value: 0 }
            ...
        ]
    }, {
        id: 2,
        columns: [
            { id: 1, value: 0 },
            { id: 2, value: 0 }
            ...
        ]
    }
]
```

This will allow this to work

```js
import {
  LightningElement,
  track
} from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {
  columns = [{
      id: '1',
      name: 'v1'
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      name: 'v2'
    },
    {
      id: '3',
      name: 'v3'
    },
    {
      id: '4',
      name: 'v4'
    },
    {
      id: '5',
      name: 'v5'
    },
  ]

  records = [{
      id: '1',
      columns: [{
          id: '1',
          value: 0
        },
        {
          id: '2',
          value: 0
        },
        {
          id: '3',
          value: 0
        },
        {
          id: '4',
          value: 0
        },
        {
          id: '5',
          value: 0
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      columns: [{
          id: '1',
          value: 0
        },
        {
          id: '2',
          value: 0
        },
        {
          id: '3',
          value: 0
        },
        {
          id: '4',
          value: 0
        },
        {
          id: '5',
          value: 0
        },
      ]
    }
  ]

  visitValueChange(event) {
    const recordId = event.target.dataset.recordId
    const columnId = event.target.dataset.columnId
    const value = event.target.value

    const record = this.records.find(record => record.id === recordId)
    const column = record.columns.find(column => column.id === columnId)

    column.value = value
  }
}
```

```html
<template>
  <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
        <template for:each={columns} for:item="column">
          <th key={column.id}>{column.name}</th>
        </template>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <template for:each={records} for:item="record">
        <tr key={record.id}>
          <template for:each={record.columns} for:item="column">
            <td key={column.id}>
              <lightning-input
                variant="label-hidden"
                class="fieldSize"
                type="number"
                step="0.01"
                label="visitValue"
                value={column.value}
                data-record-id={record.id}
                data-column-id={column.id}
                onchange={visitValueChange} 
                placeholder="00.00"
              ></lightning-input>
            </td>
          </template>
        </tr>
      </template>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>
```